# solving a maze using the left hand rule

Tags: java, maze

i am trying to solve the maze using the left hand exit rule using the the below sudo code 
i have got it working mostly but i am having issues with making it choose a new direction when it hits a dead end and comes back(like in the case of a square whose top is true but left, bottom and right walls are false during the first phase my code correctly moves from say if entry was left to either of the 2 that is bottom or right but when it comes back it chooses the left direction and not the bottom,how do i make it choose bottom).

could some one advise me on how to choose the new direction - i have put double asterisk (**) around the method in question for your ref
thanks in advance

```
Set int entr to LEFT;
Set int exit to-1;
Set boolean backtrack to false;
Set currentSquare to startingSquare;
Set previousSquare to null;
Set currentSquare.onpath to true;
While (currentSquare != endingSquare) {
    **Set exit to currentSquare.getLeftHandExit(entr);**
    Set previousSquare to currentSquare;
    Set currentSquare to currentSquare.adjacentSquare(exit);
    If (backtracking is false and exit is same as entrance)
        Set backtracking to true;
        Remove previousSquare from path;
    }
    Else if backtracking is true and currentSquare is not on the path
        Set backtracking to false;
        Add previousSquare to path;
    }
    If backtracking is true, remove currentSquare from path;
    else add currentSquare to path;
    entr = currentSquare.oppositeSide(exit);
} // end of While
```

Comment: That is no sudo code. With sudo, you can just walk though walls ;-)

Comment: Becuase it looks like English isn't your native language, you might not get the subtlety of what Thilo is saying, so I'll translate. The correct term for what you've posted is **pesudocode** (pronounced *sudo code* the way you spelled it). Thilo is making a joke on the fact that **sudo** is a UNIX utility that lets you run commands as a the system administrator, in effect being able to do whatever you want.

Comment: thank you guys for your faithful comments to improve my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always turn to the left then just turn around, and you should change the direction, so your left side changes to what was the right side.

When you get to the next hallway you will still turn left.

I think of it as just keep your left hand on the wall, and you will eventually find your way out.

Depending on how complicated your maze can be, it is possible to design a maze where you will end up in loop, so you may want to change colors of where you have been so you can detect when you went both ways through some section, or am repeating your path again.

Comment: thanks i read ur answer like 5 times b4 getting what i needed to do in my head i mean i knew the answer but was not thinking in the right way

Answer (score 1):

Use a backtracking system; whether it is by using a recursive method (not preferrable) or a stack to walk back the step. Ideally, you'd also set markers in every junction that your algorithm choose a way in, so you do not choose the same path again (choose only unmarked paths in a given junction)

Wikipedia has some [nice pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm) on how to achieve this. Pay attention to the "Recursive backtracker" algorithm, replacing the "Choose randomly one of the unvisited neighbours" by "Choose left turn from one of the unvisited neighbours" (meaning choosing clock-wise from the left cell).

Also, check out [this e-book](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780471701460/chapter-8-recursive-backtracking/backtracking_through_a_maze#X2ludGVybmFsX0ZsYXNoUmVhZGVyP3htbGlkPTk3ODA0NzE3MDE0NjAvMTA1) about recursivity.

I'd go for something like (untested code) :

```
maze.clearAllVisited();
Stack<Point> paths = new Stack<Point>();
int x = maze.getStartX();
int y = maze.getStartY();
while (!maze.isExit(x, y)) {
   maze.setVisited(x, y);
   if (maze.canGoWest(x, y)) {    // check if west cell is accessible from x,y and has not been visited
      paths.push(new Point(x, y));
      x--;
   } else if (maze.canGoNorth(x, y)) { // check if north cell is accessible from x,y and has not been visited
      paths.push(new Point(x, y));
      y--;
   } else if (maze.canGoEast(x, y)) {  // ...
      paths.push(new Point(x, y));
      x++;
   } else if (maze.canGoSouth(x, y)) { // ...
      paths.push(new Point(x, y));
      y++;
   } else {
      if (paths.isEmpty()) {
         break;  // no more path for backtracking, exit (aka no solution for maze)
      }
      // dead end! go back!
      Point last = stack.pop();
      x = last.x;
      y = last.y;
   }   
}
```

Comment: thanks dude but there is an easier way to do it without stacks and it is the guy above that won

Comment: if (s == Sides.L){
   if(!m.hasSide(Sides.T))return Sides.T;
   else if (!m.hasSide(Sides.R))return Sides.R;
   else if(!m.hasSide(Sides.B))return Sides.B;
   else return s;
   }
  else if (s == Sides.T){
   if(!m.hasSide(Sides.R))return Sides.R;
   else if (!m.hasSide(Sides.B))return Sides.B;
   else if(!m.hasSide(Sides.L))return Sides.L;
   else return s;
   }

Comment: above is part of my code, it should provide u with enough input that u should be able write the remaining on your own

Comment: @DRM1981, I understand why you'd prefer using the right-hand solution for a maze solver, after all there are more than one "good" way of getting from point A to point B (abstracting the maze problem here). The question now is; if you prefer the other solution, why did you paste some code under my answer now? Why would I need to "write the remaining on [my] own"? I already wrote a maze path finder, and found that use my suggested solution, added a random path chooser may lead to faster solution finding than the naïve approach.. And there are yet even more complex algorithms. Please clarify.

Comment: @Yanick that code is not for you but for some people who i know still wanted to know the answer.And i agree that your code is much faster.But i did not really care on the speed aspect of it. Thanks though. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @DRM1981, alright. Fair enough. There were no mention of who that comment was addressed to, so I didn't know. Cheers!

Comment: It's not gonna work if the the mouse is going down, i.e. south. Because the left in this case is East not West.

Comment: @ForzaGreen you are right. It should be called `canTurnLeft` and `canTurnRight` instead, with `canForward` and `canBackward` to replace North and South,, then set the new facing direction (North, South, East or West).

Comment: @ForzaGreen that being said, the proposed code is not really a "left hand rule", but it's nevertheless more simple and as efficient.